# How to enforce HTTPS traffic to Flexible Google App Engine with custom domain?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have a site on Google Domains (http://example.com).

But I want it should redirect to https://example.com on flexible app engine environment.

what changes required in app.yaml for flexible app engine environment.

Mu current app.yaml as below:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Comment: No changes are required to app.yaml. Follow this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl

Comment: @JohnHanley I have gone through a document I have done this setps currently, my example.com domain working both http and https request. My requirement is should work only on https. All requests should open using https://  not through http://

Comment: You will need to check the protocol in your code and for HTTP redirect the user with a 301 or 307 to HTTPS. Nothing is provided for you by App Engine Flexible. You provide the logic in your code.

Comment: @JohnHanley Can you show me sample application. How we can redirect?

Answer (score 1):

In order to redirect HTTP to HTTPS using a Flask application in App Engine Flexible Environment you only need to use the small Flask extension called [Talisman](https://pypi.org/project/flask-talisman).

In your `requirements.txt` you have to add a line containing `flask-talisman`.

In your `main.py` you just have to import `Talisman` and wrap your Flask app with it:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_talisman import Talisman

app = Flask(__name__)
Talisman(app)
```

By default, doing this redirects to HTTPS.

Take into account that Talisman is not an official Google product, experimental or otherwise.